# joomla custom registration field with custom processing

Tags: plugins, joomla, registration, custom-fields

I used testprofile plugin to add a custom fields to joomla default registration,what I want to do is to add a mobile number field and have some custom processing on it such as sending a verification code to this mobile number,the problem is that I don't know where to do such processing and where to check this field?

Comment: There is no extension that I know of or can see on the JED site which caters for your requirements, however this might be a possible alternative: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/spam-protection/26540

Comment: I tested this plugin before but it didn't work correctly and it resulted design problems on j3.3 .